# otool is referencing an old version of libffi

Tags: llvm, macos-catalina, otool, libffi

I'm trying to compile an R package (which compiles in Linux) on Mac OS 10.15.7.

I'm getting a weird problem right at the end of the installation, related to `llvm-objdump-mp-7.0` referencing `/opt/local/bin/libffi.7.dylib`.

The problem seems to be with my Xcode/homebrew toolsets somehow being out of sync.

I can generate the problem with

```
$otool --version
llvm-otool(1): Apple Inc. version cctools-921
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-7.0/lib/libLLVM.dylib
  Reason: image not found
fatal error: otool: fatal error in /opt/local/bin/llvm-objdump-mp-7.0
```

However,

```
$ ls /opt/local/lib/libffi*
/opt/local/lib/libffi.8.dylib   /opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libffi.a
```

I've run `brew update` followed by `brew upgrade` and `brew reinstall libffi` and `brew reinstall llvm`

I've upgraded my Xcode to 12.4, as well as installing the command line tools.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have previously installed an older version of `llvm` which put its commands in `/usr/local/bin`, which then masked the system version of `/usr/bin/otool`.

The current `llvm` formula puts the updated tools in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin` so as to not mask the Xcode versions.  However, the older versions were still living in `/usr/local/bin`.

The following commands seemed to fix me.

```
sudo rm /opt/local/bin/otool
sudo rm /opt/local/bin/llvm-otool
sudo rm /opt/local/bin/*-mp-7.0
```

`otools` is now properly finding the Xcode version, so I'm up and running again.